# How to return class type for decoding codable in swift

Tags: swift, generics, codable

I am trying to make a service class that would also have the decoding class type of the respective api with it

```
import UIKit

struct LoginResponse: Codable {
    var action: String
    var result: String
    var key: String
}

struct LogoutResponse: Codable {
    var action: String
    var result: String
}

enum Api {
    case login
    case logout
    
    var backingType: Codable {
        switch self {
        case .login:
            return LoginResponse.self as! Codable
        case .logout:
            return LogoutResponse.self as! Codable
        }
    }
}
let loginResponse = LoginResponse(action: "login", result: "result", key: "key")
let loginData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(loginResponse)

let decodedData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Api.login.backingType, from: loginData)
```

The error I am getting is ->

**Cannot convert value of type 'Codable.Type' (aka '(Decodable & Encodable).Type') to expected argument type 'T.Type'

Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.**

I also tried using generics

```
import UIKit

struct LoginResponse: Codable {
    var action: String
    var result: String
    var key: String
}

struct LogoutResponse: Codable {
    var action: String
    var result: String
}

enum Api<T: Codable> {
    case login
    case logout
    
    var backingType: Codable.Type {
        switch self {
        case .login:
            return LoginResponse.self
        case .logout:
            return LogoutResponse.self
        }
    }
    
    var genericBackingType: T.Type {
        switch self {
        case .login:
            return LoginResponse.self as! T.Type
        case .logout:
            return LogoutResponse.self as! T.Type
        }
    }
}
let loginResponse = LoginResponse(action: "login", result: "result", key: "key")
let loginData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(loginResponse)
let decodedData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Api.login.backingType as! Codable.Type, from: loginData)
```

Please point me in a suitable direction

Comment: What do you expect the type of `decodedData` to be?

Comment: @Sweeper The object of the struct from the backingType variable. if login is passed it should be of type LoginResponse, else LogoutResponse.

Answer (score 0):

In both attempts the type to be decoded must be a concrete type, it cannot be a protocol.

---

In such a case the most suitable solution is an enum with associated types

```
enum Api : Decodable {
    case login(LoginResponse)
    case logout(LogoutResponse)
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case action, result, key }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let action = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .action)
        let result = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .result)
        switch action {
            case "login":
                let key = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .key)
                self = .login(LoginResponse(action: action, result: result, key: key))
            case "logout":
                self = .logout(LogoutResponse(action: action, result: result))
            default : throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .action, in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid action: \(action)")
        }
    }
}
```

It decodes the `action` key and depending on the value it returns the appropriate case with the associated response type.

The structs can be the same, you could even omit the `action` member if in real life the structs are never going to be encoded. If so you can further omit the `LogoutResponse` struct and use the associated type `String` for the `result` in the `logout` case.

```
struct LoginResponse : Codable {
    let action: String
    let result: String
    let key: String
}

struct LogoutResponse : Codable {
    let action: String
    let result: String
}
```

And the way to decode the stuff is

```
let loginResponse = LoginResponse(action: "login", result: "result", key: "key")
let loginData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(loginResponse)

let decodedApi = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Api.self, from: loginData)
switch decodedApi {
    case .login(let response): print(response)
    case .logout(let response): print(response)
}
```